# Emacs exclude a keyword from indentation (Verilog)

Tags: emacs, verilog, indentation

I have an issue with using the following emacs indentation option

setq verilog-cexp-indent

I want to set it to 4 to apply for 1 line if-else, for, case .. etc

But when I do, it indents the module keyword.
Can I exclude the "module keyword" from this or is there a better way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the instructions to Verilog mode.  To do that, do `M-x find-library<RET>verilog-mode<RET>`.  In there you'll see (amongst other information):

```
;;   ;; User customization for Verilog mode
;;   (setq verilog-indent-level             3
;;         verilog-indent-level-module      3
;;         verilog-indent-level-declaration 3
;;         verilog-indent-level-behavioral  3
;;         verilog-indent-level-directive   1
;;         verilog-case-indent              2
;;         verilog-auto-newline             t
;;         verilog-auto-indent-on-newline   t
;;         verilog-tab-always-indent        t
;;         verilog-auto-endcomments         t
;;         verilog-minimum-comment-distance 40
;;         verilog-indent-begin-after-if    t
;;         verilog-auto-lineup              'declarations
;;         verilog-linter                   "my_lint_shell_command"
;;         )
```